# How to assign a value to a variable in struts from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jsp, variables, struts2, variable-assignment

Good morning, I have been working on this problem for a while and I didn't found a solution in google for it.

There is a way to assign a value to a variable in Struts from JavaScript? I'm new working with Struts so is costing me a little..

This is a part of the code I'm using:

In some part of the code first i create this little guy:

```
<input type="hidden" name="identificadorProspecto" id="identificadorProspecto" value="-1">
```

After making some connections to data base I update this value

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" >
    var idContainer = document.getElementById('identificadorProspecto');
    alert("idContainer.value: "+contenedorIdentificacion.value);
</script>

<s:url id="car_suc_xx223" action="listar_sucursales.action" >
    <s:param name="cod_prospecto" value="%{identificadorProspecto}" />
</s:url>
```

When i get the alert message, I don't receive the same value that I get in the 
`value="%{identificadorProspecto}"` (this one has some random value)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using a `property` tag. For example

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var idContainer = document.getElementById('identificadorProspecto');
    idContainer.value = '<s:property value="%{identificadorProspecto}">'; 
    alert("idContainer.value: "+idContainer.value);
</script>
```

Comment: How I can to adapt this answer to set up a list in struts to null? or an empty list?

Comment: @jaundavid You can't do it because it's a different question.